# Polymer: Observing array mutations with complex observer

Tags: javascript, arrays, polymer, polymer-1.0, observers

I want a complex observer that observes changes to an array and a property:

```
properties: {
  list: {
    type: Array,
    value: ["foo"],
  },
  prop: {
    type: Number,
    value: 10,
  }
},

observers: [
  'onChange(prop, list.splices)',
],

onChange: function() {
  console.log('something changed!');
},
```

This works only after something changes in the original list, but it is not triggered after both properties are initialized, nor when `prop` changes before anything changes in the original list.

It is curious that if I put two observers, one for `prop` and one for `list.splices`, they work as expected, being triggered on initialization. (EDIT: there is [an issue](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/3878) for this behavior)

What is the correct way to observe changes to both, array mutations and a property, at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
observers: [
  'onChange(prop, list.*)',
],
```

Comment: Nice. I have the feeling that using wildcard could affect performance if the list is too big or items are too complex. But I couldn't find any information supporting this, do you know?

Comment: As per `Polymer's` documentation `wildcards` are used to observer changes to both `mutation` and `sub-properties`. So, as compared to `splice` it should have performance impact, but not sure about how much impact will it have based on size of list.

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround is having two observers that call the same function:

```
observers: [
  'onChange(prop, list.splices)',
  'onChange(prop, list)',
],
```